# How does DataStax Spark Cassandra connector create SparkContext?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, sbt, spark-cassandra-connector

I have run the following Spark test program successfully. In this program I notice the "cassandraTable" method and "getOrCreate" method in SparkContext class. But I am not able to find it in the Spark Scala API docs for this class. What am I missing in understanding this code? I am trying to understand how this SparkContext is different when Datastax Connector is in sbt.

Code -

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

object CassandraInt {

def main(args:Array[String]){

   val SparkMasterHost = "127.0.0.1"
   val CassandraHost = "127.0.0.1"
   val conf = new SparkConf(true)
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", CassandraHost)
    .set("spark.cleaner.ttl", "3600")
    .setMaster("local[12]")
    .setAppName(getClass.getSimpleName)

   // Connect to the Spark cluster:
   lazy val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)

   val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "kv")
   println(rdd.count)
   println(rdd.map(_.getInt("value")).sum)    
  }}
```

The build.sbt file I used is -

```
name := "Test Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0"

addCommandAlias("c1", "run-main CassandraInt")

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.0-M3"

fork in run := true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not different. Spark supports only one active `SparkContext` and `getOrCreate` is a method defined on [the companion object](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext$):

> This function may be used to get or instantiate a SparkContext and register it as a singleton object. Because we can only have one active SparkContext per JVM, this is useful when applications may wish to share a SparkContext.
>
> This method allows not passing a SparkConf (useful if just retrieving).

To summarize:

- If there is an active context it returns it.
- Otherwise it creates a new one.

`cassandraTable` is a method of the [`SparkContextFunctions`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/75719dfe0e175b3e0bb1c06127ad4e6930c73ece/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/streaming/StreamingContextFunctions.scala#L15) exposed using an [implicit conversion](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/75719dfe0e175b3e0bb1c06127ad4e6930c73ece/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/package.scala#L57).